# Пересохранить файл на сервере Django Python

Tags: python, django, ffmpeg

Скорей всего я не полностью написал вопрос в заголовке. Прошу прощения.

В общем работа моя застряла на том что я не могу занести файл с сервера в соответствующую модель Django.
Опишу всю последовательность моих действий.

1. Изначально я загружаю видеофайл на сервер и сохраняю его в модель которая просто нужна для того что бы я мог нормально работать с ffmpeg. Так как пока он хранится в памяти я ничего с ним делать не могу.
2. Потом идёт извлечение файла из модели с записью в переменную. И их неё уже при помощи ffmpeg идёт нарезка нескольких постеров для тега poster="" видео. А так же перебор папки при помощи os.listdir() и отправки их в браузер, что бы пользователь мог выбрать какой будет постер у видео.
3. Теперь наступает очередь конвертирования видео при помощи ffmpeg. Вот тут и встаёт загвоздка.
   То есть по сути теперь мне нужно взять этот видеофайл пелеложить его в другую папку и записать в базу в models.FileFiel(). Но как это сделать я пока что не могу даже представить.
   Пожалуйста помогите решить данную проблемму.